# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at populateList (script.js:22) at HTMLFormElement.addItem (script.js:17)

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to fix the error but it's not happening it's still saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null     at populateList (script.js:22)     at HTMLFormElement.addItem (script.js:17)

```js
const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
const items = [];

function addItem(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 //console.log('Hello');
 const text = (this.querySelector('[name=item]')).value;
 const item = {
  text,
  done: false
 };
 //console.log(item);
 items.push(item);
 populateList(items, itemsList);
 this.reset();
}

function populateList(plates = [], platesList) {
 platesList.innerHTML = plates.map((plate, i) => {
  return `
   <li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-index=${i} id="item${i}" checked />
    <label for="item${i}">${plate.text}</label>
   </li>
  `;
 }).join('');
}

addItems.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>LOCAL TAPAS</h2>
  <p></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Loading Tapas...</li>
  </ul>
  <form class="add-items">
    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Name" required>
    <input type="submit" value="+ Add Item">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Not you're problem, but *reduce* would be a better choice than *map*, it saves creating an unnecessary array and avoids the *join*. Semantics really.

Answer (score 1):

Add class `class="plates"` to the `ul` tag

```js
const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
const items = [];

function addItem(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 //console.log('Hello');
 const text = (this.querySelector('[name=item]')).value;
 const item = {
  text,
  done: false
 };
 //console.log(item);
 items.push(item);
 populateList(items, itemsList);
 this.reset();
}

function populateList(plates = [], platesList) {
 platesList.innerHTML = plates.map((plate, i) => {
  return `
   <li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-index=${i} id="item${i}" checked />
    <label for="item${i}">${plate.text}</label>
   </li>
  `;
 }).join('');
}

addItems.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>LOCAL TAPAS</h2>
  <p></p>
  <ul class="plates">
    <li>Loading Tapas...</li>
  </ul>
  <form class="add-items">
    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Name" required>
    <input type="submit" value="+ Add Item">
  </form>

</div>
```